# how to get data in total ,maintax,payable amount field as i changed the quantity

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i just want to fetch the value from 3 rows using jquery and calculate then displays to bottom field

[image]

Comment: multiply the quantity  and price

Comment: please add your code

Comment: You could use keyUp() function([here](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)) - inside the function make the calculations and show result to the element that you want

Comment: i just want to fetch the value from 3 rows using jquery and calculate then displays to bottom field

Comment: Please provide a working code example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery change event ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/)).

```
$( "input.amount" ).change(function() {
    var amount = $( this ).val();
    // calculations:
    // var total = amount * ...

    $('#total').val(total);
    // ...
});
```